# achart engine settings

Tags: android, achartengine

I've tried to use achart engine but the documentation is somewhat unclear. I've also tried looking through the examples.

Could someone explain how to increase the thickness of the lines in the bar graph that's attached? Also, I would like to separate each bar into it's own series but I haven't had luck doing so (my code is below the image). I've been working on this issue for a really long time!

[image]

```
public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getBarDemoRenderer() {
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Entering getBarDemoRenderer");
     XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();   
     renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(18);
     renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
     renderer.setLabelsTextSize(18);
     renderer.setLegendTextSize(14);
     renderer.setMargins(new int[] {20, 30, 15, 0});
     int[] color = {Color.RED, Color.CYAN,Color.YELLOW, Color.LTGRAY,Color.MAGENTA, Color.GREEN, Color.WHITE};

     for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
         SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
         r.setColor(color[i]);
         renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);  
     }

     int renderCount = renderer.getSeriesRendererCount();
     Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Renderer series count =  " + renderCount);

     return renderer;
 }

 private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getApplianceDataset() {

     XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

     try{

         CategorySeries series = null;
         for (Map.Entry<String,Float> entry : list.entrySet()) {
             String key = entry.getKey();
             series = new CategorySeries (key);
             String b=String.valueOf(entry.getValue());
             double value=Double.valueOf(b);
             series.add(value);   
             dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());
         }

     }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
         Log.e(LOG_TAG, "IllegalArgumentException " + e.toString());
         Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to show chart", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }

     int dataSeriesCount = dataset.getSeriesCount();
     return dataset;
 }


    private void setChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {         
        renderer.setChartTitle("Test Bar Chart");
        renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        renderer.setXTitle("Appliance");
        renderer.setYTitle("Watt Hours (wh)");
        renderer.setXAxisMax(3);
        renderer.setXAxisMin(0.0);
        renderer.setYAxisMax(1800);
        renderer.setYAxisMin(0);   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in setChartSettings give

```
        renderer.setBarSpacing(1.0f);
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] {10, 10, 10, 0});
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much! This works (except that the lower the bar spacing, the larger the bars). So, renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5f) resulted in a larger bar than renderer.setBarSpacing(1.0f). After you specified the method to do this, I was able to look up setBarSpacing and found the same question:  http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/issues/detail?id=145. Thx again!